# Make authorization with social networks OAuth 2.0 at smartphone app

Tags: security, authentication, oauth-2.0, authorization, social-networking

we are making game for smartphone and want to make social netwok authentication and authorization but met a big problem:

we successfully implemented VK.com or Facebook authentification via OAuth 2.0 (client flow via WebView), but if sombody got access_token of users using **other fishing app** we are will accept this access_token because it will be still valid for social network and cheater will have **full access** to user profile because, corresponding to OAuth 2.0 protocol it is not possible to get source (app id or something) of access_token creation.

So what is the easiest and best way to implement authorization based on OAuth 2.0 authentification, so we able to know that user got his access_token in our application, not other one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is very simple: just use Authorization Code Flow instead Implicit Flow, than even if thief will change "code" flow to accepted from his fishing application Auth Sever will not generate access token, because of wrong client_id (different from which *code* was received)